# Is there a Bib entry type that combinds Online and Book?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

Often I'd like to cite an electronic version of a book. It will be by a scientific publisher, and have all the publisher, editor, etc. information, but has a URL and an accessed-on date instead of a page number. I've got to choose between @book which won't give the URL and pretend I went and got the hardcopy (Which seems unethical) and @online which misses half the information and makes it look like I used a website. Is there a way to add the accessed on date and URL to a full book entry? Or some form of hybrid style?

Example books: IUPAC gold book. CRC Handbook of Chemistry And Physics.

Comment: With standard `biblatex` styles, `@book`s also support `url` and `urldate` fields quite admirably (of course not if you have turned them off via `url=false`). Actually `biblatex-chicago`, `biblatex-apa`, `biblatex-ieee` all seem very happy to do that as well.

Comment: If your style for whatever reason does not support URLs you can always use the `addendum`, `note` or `howpublished` (if applicable, `biblatex` does not support `howpublished` for all types) fields. The `biblatex-chem` styles all have `url=false` by default, with `url=true` added they also support URLs. The only style that really didn't want to print a URL was `mla`.

Comment: @moewe Durr, that would be it; I use biblatex-chem most of the time (achemso or rsc the rest), which would make sense. I'll try it with URL=True. Thank you.

Comment: So what do we do about this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex`'s standard styles have no trouble (and no scruple) at all to display a `url` and `urldate` for `@book`s or any other entry type.

This feature can be turned off via `url=off`, in which case only `@online` entries retain their URLs (see §3.1.2.2 *Style-specific [Preamble Options]*, p. 55 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

Most custom styles available from CTAN work similarly ([`biblatex-chicago`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago), [`biblatex-apa`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa), [`biblatex-ieee`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee), [`biblatex-nature`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nature), [`philosophy-modern`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-philosophy)), some have `url=false` pre-set (the [`biblatex-chem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chem) family seems to be an example), so you will have to issue `url=true` to see the URL.
The only style I found that wouldn't print URLs for `@book`s was [`biblatex-mla`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-mla).

In case your style does not support URL fields, you can always go for `addendum` and `note`, or even `howpublished` (`biblatex` supports `howpublished` only for some entry types).